# Turning Procs into Block confusion

Tags: ruby

I understand that we use the ampersand in front of the method's argument in order to avoid using yield, which would output an error if it doesn't find a block in its way.

However, I've seen that sometimes we use the & in front of the argumenent when we call a method, in order to transform the proc back into a block. It eventually happens that there are 2 ampersands, one for turning blocks into procs, and the second for the opposite.

How's that?! When do we need to put the ampersand to getting back a block from a proc, and why?

I hope I've been clear, beacause not being english mother tongue could make harsh to pose difficult questions for me.

Example

I took this example from the slides of CodeSchool, which can be found on http://courseware.codeschool.com/ruby_bits_2/ruby_bits_2_level_1.pdf.

```
class Timeline
attr_accessor :tweets
  def each(&block)
     tweets.each(&block)
  end
end
```

Comment: Show some code. It's not clear what you mean.

Comment: Can you just post two simple examples for the two different cases that you think are ?

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that we use the ampersand in front of the method's
>   argument in order to avoid using yield, which would output an error if
>   it doesn't find a block in its way.

Your understanding is wrong.

You use `&block` as the last argument to capture the block into a `Proc`, in particular to store it and use it later on. When calling a method, `&block` does the reverse, i.e. specifies that the block corresponds to the given `block`. This is the same idea as `def foo(*args)` and `foo(*args)`.

The example you gave is basically equivalent to:

```
def each
   tweets.each{|t| yield y}
end
```

As Yehuda Katz explains at the end of [this talk](http://blip.tv/rupy-strongly-dynamic-conference/yehuda-katz-tradeoffs-and-choices-why-ruby-isn-t-python-5726460), you should think of a "block" as a `Proc` with a special argument position and a dedicated syntax to specify it.

Comment: Sorry but not being native english, and having difficult finding some good example in my own language (which is Italian by the way, if anyone knows a good resource) I'm not so sure about the second step. It's fine, I save block in procs so I can use them wheneven I want, but could you please give me an example of when I need to change procs back into blocks?

Answer (score 1):

It's common to use them together. This is the case because blocks can't be used as parameters, while procs can. So if you need to use the block as a parameter within the method's body, you must turn it into a proc.

Within that method, you might want to pass the proc to another method that only accepts a block, so you have to do the conversion once again.

For example:

```
def each(&block) # block to proc
  posts.each(&block) # proc to block
end
```